# Webpack2 node-libs-browser exclude?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I've upgraded to webpack 2 and before tree shaking my bundle size has increased. When investigating why it seems I have large files like `bn.js` and `eliptic` (some dependencies of node-libs-browser - which itself is now a dependency of webpack2). Is there any way to remove these or exclude them? In webpack1 they weren't being added to my bundle.

Comment: Same problem here now; did you ever find a solution?  My chunk size is much larger even after tree shaking (about 25% larger for my vendor chunk).

Comment: We found that the files being included were as a result of webpack polyfills (bn.js being included as a polyfil for using node crypto) and they just seem to be larger than what webpack1 inlcuded (I guess)

Comment: Ah, yeah, I knew that they were webpack polyfills, but I don't understand why additional ones are now being included.  Webpack *should* only be including the polyfills that it detects as needed and it's pulling in lots that aren't needed at all.  I'm using the NormalModuleReplacementPlugin to stub out the ones that I know that I don't need with `node-noop` which resolves the size issue, but it's possible I'll stub out the wrong ones - I'd rather webpack actually only grabbed what it needs rather than the whole damn lot.

Comment: I'm also seeing this... surely we're not expected to ship a elliptic curve library with every app even if it doesn't need it?

Comment: Same problem with me also, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Never did find a solution, we just ended up removing the libraries that were causing webpack to include the polyfills. In the case on bn.js it was being included because we did some md5 hashing on the client.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is because webpack by default applies its internal plugin `NodeSourcePlugin` [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/60824f1bab53aa7ffc74495ac9cee7a979a7983d/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js#L75) or [here for webworker](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/60824f1bab53aa7ffc74495ac9cee7a979a7983d/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js#L86), and if you have a module that even references a NodeJS module like `crypto`, ie: `var Crypto = canUseDom ? null : require("crypto")`, webpack will bundle a bunch of big files to simulate NodeJS.  See issue filed here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4976.

The solution is to avoid any code that references NodeJS internal modules, even if they are not used on the browser.

To catch these, you can remove `NodeSourcePlugin` by overriding the `target` option.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const FunctionModulePlugin = require("webpack/lib/FunctionModulePlugin");

const output = {
  path: process.cwd() + "/build",
  filename: "bundle.[hash].js"
};

{
  target: () => undefined,
  output,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.JsonpTemplatePlugin(output),
    new FunctionModulePlugin(output),
    new webpack.LoaderTargetPlugin("web"),
  ]
}
```

Edit: with webpack 3, it's now as simple as:

```
const webpackConfig = {
  node: false
}
```

If you must have code that's for server side only and references NodeJS modules, it's better to separate those into their own module, and export a dummy copy through the `browser` field in `package.json`.

Edit: I wrote a blog related to this issue here https://medium.com/walmartlabs/webpack-optimization-a-case-study-92b130334b6c.